# How do I write tests for the functionality of Django admin pages?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-admin, django-testing

Disclaimer: I'm new to Django and testing

I have some models in Django admin, but I'm overriding the save_model() function of a particular model. I'm unable to test Model.create() because the admin save_model() override isn't called. What would be the right way to test this function? Any example code would be very much appreciated :) Here's mine:

models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50000)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, 
        help_text='Leave this blank to automatically generate a path.', 
        blank=True
    )
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('publication date', default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
class NavigationInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Navigation

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 120,     
        'rows': 20})
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = ('title', 'pub_date')
        model = Page


class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['title', 'content', 'path']}),
        ('Scheduling', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    form = PageForm
    inlines = [NavigationInline]

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    # All kinds of craziness to be tested!
```

Answer (score 7):

In the end I used the django client. I didn't do this initially because I was having trouble with a 'managementform data is missing or has been tampered with' error, and I ended up checking the data posted to the form to realise that I wasn't posting the required 'TOTAL-FORMS' values. Once I added these, the client testing worked fine:

```
class ModelAdminTests(TestCase):
    def create_page(self, title, content, parent_page_id=''):
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='Password123')
        self.client.post(
            '/admin/pages/page/add/',
            {
                'title': title,
                'content': content,
                'pub_date_0': '2017-01-01',
                'pub_date_1': '12:00:00',
                'navigation-0-title': 'Home',
                'navigation-0-weight': 0,
                'navigation-0-parent': parent_page_id,
                'navigation-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',
                'navigation-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
                'navigation-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '1',
            },
            follow=True,
        )
        self.client.logout()

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', 'Password123')

    def test_route_created_with_page(self):
        """
        When a page is created, a route should always be created also.
        """
        page_title = 'Test'
        page_content = 'This is the test page.'

        self.create_page(
            title=page_title,
            content=page_content,
        )
        route = Route.objects.filter(pk=1).exists()

        self.assertTrue(route)
```